# Classification of dense and complete linear orders

Tags: general-topology, order-theory, infinitary-combinatorics

> **Question.** Is there a decent classification theorem for linear orders satisfying all three of:
>
> - *Dense.* Given a pair of elements $y,x$ with $y>x$, there exists $k$ satisfying $y>k>x$.
> - *Complete.* Given a non-empty subset $A$, if $A$ is bounded above, then $A$ has a least upper bound.
> - *Endless.* There is neither a greatest element nor a least element.

**Comments:**

- Assuming separability, [$\mathbb{R}$ is the only example.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/43148/basic-results-with-three-or-more-hypotheses/43165#43165).
- [There are other examples.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/537529/dense-and-complete-totally-ordered-sets).
- I'm happy to assume some further conditions, like "for any two points, there is an order-automorphism mapping the first point to the second." However, I'd like models of unboundedly large cardinalities.

Comment: I'm not the best-qualified to answer this, but my understanding is that this is a rather "wild" classification problem and you very quickly run into questions you can't answer in ZFC (a particularly famous example of this is [Suslin's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suslin%27s_problem)).  By the way, the homogeneity hypothesis you propose is actually extremely restrictive, as it implies every bounded well-ordered sequence in your chain $X$ is countable, which with some work can be used to show $|X|=2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: @EricWofsey, judging by that link, you seem to be right. Perhaps a classification exists under $V=L$ or something like that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the basis of Eric's comment: no.

In particular, [Suslin's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suslin%27s_problem) asks whether or not there exists a non-empty linearly ordered set $R$ that isn't isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ satisfying the 3 conditions stated in my question together with the condition: "You can't cram more than countably many disjoint non-empty open intervals into $R$." This is independent of ZFC. Therefore, it seems that no truly useful classification can exist without assuming further axioms.